# CloudFormation Elasticsearch Service - Circular dependency between resources on same resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cloudformation

thanks in advance!

I've been stuck on this issue for ages and can't find the solution...

Basically I want to implement the same access policy on my elasticsearch service but when I try to re-create this in cloudformation I receive a circular dependency error.. I know whats causing the error the Fn::GetAtt's which reference the elastic search DomainArn.

So my question is how do I go about implementing this statement without having to reference my elk domain arn?

Template contains errors.: Circular dependency between resources: [XXXXXX]

```
"XXXXXX": {
            "Type": "AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain",
            "Properties": {
                "AccessPolicies": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "AWS": {
                                    "Fn::GetAtt": ["myuser", "Arn"]
                                }
                            },
                            "Action": "es:*",
                            "Resource": {
                                "Fn::GetAtt": ["XXXXXX", "DomainArn"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "Sid": "",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "AWS": "*"
                            },
                            "Action": "es:*",
                            "Resource": {
                                "Fn::GetAtt": ["XXXXXX", "DomainArn"]
                            },
                            "Condition": {
                                "IpAddress": {
                                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                                        "xx.xx.xx.xx",
                                        "xx.xx.xx.xx"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "DomainName": "XXXXXX",
                "EBSOptions": {
                    "EBSEnabled": "True",
                    "VolumeSize": 10,
                    "VolumeType": "gp2"
                },
                "ElasticsearchClusterConfig": {
                    "InstanceCount": 1,
                    "InstanceType": "t2.small.elasticsearch"
                },
                "ElasticsearchVersion": "5.1",
                "SnapshotOptions": {
                    "AutomatedSnapshotStartHour": 0
                },
                "Tags": {
                    "Key": "name",
                    "Value": "XXXXXX"
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Did you raise this with AWS support? If nothing else they can log it as a "feature request" even though it's essentially a massive bug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than use `Fn::GetAtt` to retrieve the domain ARN, use `Fn:Sub` to construct the ARN using the rules [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-createupdatedomains.html#es-createdomain-configure-access-policies) (scroll down to "Use the following syntax to specify domain resources for Amazon ES").

```
{ "Fn::Sub":"arn:aws:es:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:domain/XXXXXX" }
```

Comment: This does not work if the domain name is not specified. If you let cloudformation create the domain name (as is recommended) then you cannot know what it will be until it's finished being created. This is a really dumb error from AWS. The AccessPolicies should be a separate resource.

Comment: Since the prefix of the generated domain name is deterministic, you can use wildcards to restrict the domain name if you use an autogenerated domain name. 
`!Sub "arn:aws:es:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:domain/${AWS::StackName}-search*"` Although hopefully it will become a separate resource in the future.